# Insert data into Sql Compact

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I have Handheld device that connect to Sql Server database, read the Sql server data and get it on the SQL Compact database that is located on device. This is my code:

```
public void InsertData() // Function insert data into SQL commapct database
{
    dt = new DataTable();
    dt = SqlServer_GetData_dt("Select id_price, price, id_item  from prices", SqlCeConnection); // get data form sql server
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string sql = "";
            sql = "insert into prices" +
                " ( id_prices, price,id_item) values('"
                    + dt.Rows[i]["id_price"].ToString().Trim() + "', '"
                    + dt.Rows[i]["price"].ToString().Trim() + "', '"
                    + dt.Rows[i]["id_item"].ToString().Trim() + "')";

            obj.SqlCE_WriteData_bit(sql, connection.ConnectionString);//insert into sql compact
        }
    }


}

public DataTable SqlServer_GetData_dt(string query, string conn)
{
    try
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string SqlCeConnection = conn;
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(SqlCeConnection);
        sqlConnection.Open();
        {

            SqlDataReader darSQLServer;
            SqlCommand cmdCESQLServer = new SqlCommand();
            cmdCESQLServer.Connection = sqlConnection;
            cmdCESQLServer.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmdCESQLServer.CommandText = query;
            darSQLServer = cmdCESQLServer.ExecuteReader();
            dt.Load(darSQLServer);
            sqlConnection.Close();
        }
        return dt;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        return dt;

    }
}
public object SqlCE_WriteData_bit(string query, string conn)
{
    try
    {
        string SqlCeConnection = conn;
        SqlCeConnection sqlConnection = new SqlCeConnection(SqlCeConnection);
        if (sqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
        }
        SqlCeCommand cmdCESQLServer = new SqlCeCommand();
        cmdCESQLServer.Connection = sqlConnection;
        cmdCESQLServer.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmdCESQLServer.CommandText = query;
        object i = cmdCESQLServer.ExecuteScalar();
        sqlConnection.Close();
        return i;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This is all work fine but the problem is that all this work very slow. I have 20 000 row that's need to be inserted into SQL compact database.

Is there any way for faster insert?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the obvious poor usage of the Connection for every call, you can greatly improve things by also eliminating the query processor altogether.  That means don't use SQL.  Instead open the destination table with `TableDirect` and a [`SqlCeResultset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceresultset(v=vs.100).aspx).  The iterate through the source data (a DataTable is a bad idea, but that's a completely different thing) and use a series of [`CreateRecord`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceresultset.createrecord(v=vs.100).aspx), [`SetValues`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceresultset.setvalues(v=vs.100).aspx) and [`Insert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceresultset.insert(v=vs.100).aspx).

[A pretty good example can be found here](http://blog.clauskonrad.net/2010/06/how-to-insert-multiple-rows-in-sql-ce.html) (though again, I'd use `SetValues` to set the entire row, not each individual field).

Answer (score 0):

Reuse your connection and don't create a new connection for every `INSERT` statement.

Instead of passing a connection string to your `SqlCE_WriteData_bit` method, create the connection once in the `InsertData` method, and pass the connection object to  `SqlCE_WriteData_bit`.

Answer (score 0):

Put all the data into a `DataTable` and then use a `SqlCeDataAdapter` to save all the data with one call to `Update`.  You may have to fiddle with the `UpdateBatchSize` to get the best performance.

Looking more closely, I see that you already have a `DataTable`.  Looping through it yourself is therefore ludicrous.  Just note that, as you have it, the `RowState` of every `DataRow` will be `Unchanged`, so they will not be inserted.  I think that you can call `DataTable.Load` such that all `RowState` values are left as `Added` but, if not, then use a `SqlDataAdapter` instead, set `AcceptChangesDuringFill` to `false` and call `Fill`.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way for faster insert?

Yes, but it probably won't be "acceptably fast enough" when we're talking about inserting 20k rows.

The problem I can see is that you are opening a connection for every single row you are retrieving from `SqlServer_GetData_dt`, that is, you open a connection to insert data 20k times...opening a connection is an expensive transaction. You should build the whole query using a `StringBuilder` object and then execute all the insert statements in one batch.

This will bring some performance gains but don't expect it to solve you're problem, inserting 20k rows will still take some time, specially if indexes need to be re-built. My suggestion is that you should thoroughly analyse your requirements and be a bit smarter about how you approach it. Options are:

- bundle a pre-populated database if possible so your app doesn't have to suffer the population process performance penalties
- if not, run the `insert` process in the background and access the data only when the pre-population is finished